# How to get the Transducer Serial Number from a stylus when drawing?

Tags: android, hid, stylus-pen

I'm developing a stylus accessory for use with an Android app. I have specified the Transducer Serial Number field (0x5B) in the HID description for the stylus as specified here: https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/stylus.html . How can I get the Transducer Serial Number when drawing with the stylus, i.e. through a MotionEvent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you can't at the moment.